# How to play an audio file in the background after clicking a link? (no embed)

Tags: html, audio

Currently I am using following code to play some audio after a link is clicked:

```
<a href="http://somehost.com/word_audio.ogg">Pronunciation of a word</a>
```

For now if the user clicks on the link, a new page with an audio playing panel is loaded. After playing the audio, the user has to click `GO BACK` button of the browser to get back to the original content.

Is it possible to play the audio without being directed to a new page? When the user clicks on the link, the audio just plays in the background?
 (Don't want to use embed because it's just a 1 second audio for a word's pronunciation as a minor explanation of an uncommon word).

Comment: @chsdk Sorry for my late reply. I just tested it and it works great. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the `href` attribute is redirecting you to the new page, you can use `e.prevenDefault()` in the link `click` event handler to stop this redirection and create a dynamic `audio` element with this `href` as source and play it.

This is what you need:

```js
function playItHere(e, link) {
  var audio = document.createElement("audio");
  var src = document.createElement("source");
  src.src = link.href;
  audio.appendChild(src);
  audio.play();
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<a href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/4/45/ACDC_-_Back_In_Black-sample.ogg" onclick="playItHere(event, this)">Pronunciation of a word</a>
```

Comment: I just tested again, it works in Chrome and Firefox, but in Safari, it doesn't work (nothing happens after the link is clicked).

Comment: @JoeHuang Yes [it has **no support in Safari**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement#Browser_compatibility), unfortunately it's a big problem with [**HTMLMediaElement**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement#Browser_compatibility)s like `audio` and `video`.

Answer (score 1):

In html5, you can actually use the `<audio>` tag to get that done!

```
<audio src="/music/myaudio.ogg" autoplay> Sorry, your browser does not support the <audio> element. </audio>
```

SOURCE: [Wired](https://www.wired.com/2010/02/embed_audio_and_video_in_html_5_pages/#Using_the_.3Caudio.3E_tag)

Answer (score 0):

If you use a tag be careful with href . 
Code snippet fixed . 
  First you will need to make convert ogg to the mp3 and than use it for multi source .

Small browser detector (**chrome/opera/safari** - mp3 and **mozilla** - ogg . )

```js
E("PLAYER").addEventListener("error", function(e) { 
      
   console.log("error: " + e.target.error)
       
});

function PLAYER_BACKGROUND(what) {
 
 var SOURCE_PATH = E(what).getAttribute("whattoplay")
 
   if (isChrome == true)
   {
 
      SOURCE_PATH = SOURCE_PATH.replace(".ogg" , ".mp3")
      
   }
   else {
   
      SOURCE_PATH = SOURCE_PATH.replace( ".mp3" , ".ogg" )
      
   }
 
  E("PLAYER").src = SOURCE_PATH 
  E("PLAYER").play() 
    
 }
```

```html
<script>

var E = function(id){return document.getElementById(id)};
var isChrome = /Chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent) || /Safari/.test(navigator.userAgent);

</script>

<a id="audio_1" onclick="PLAYER_BACKGROUND(this.id)" whattoplay="https://maximumroulette.com/framework/res/audio/laser7.ogg" href="javascript:void(0)">Pronunciation of a word</a>

<audio style="display:none" id="PLAYER" autoplay controls>

 <source src="#" type="audio/ogg">
 <source src="#" type="audio/mpeg">
Sorry, your browser does not support the  element. 

</audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

This work really well thank you.
But, how can I stop earlier clicked-music before playing the next clicked on another music. Right now, when I click multiple mp3 links, its overlapping.

```js
 
 function playItHere(e, link) {
   var audio = document.createElement("audio");
   var src = document.createElement("source");
   src.src = link.href;
   audio.appendChild(src);
   audio.play();
   e.preventDefault();
 }
```

```html
 
 <a href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/4/45/ACDC_-_Back_In_Black-sample.ogg"
 onclick="playItHere(event, this)">Pronunciation of a word</a>
```